# Add constraint on jsonb column to check if one of a set of strings in the columns values

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, check-constraints

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a constraint on a postgresql table’s column which is of type jsonb. The constraint will check and ensure that at least one of the values is in a predefined list of strings. What is the syntax to accomplish this?

so for example if there is an array of stings `[“test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]`

inside the value of the column we want to ensure that one of those strings are in the value.

Below is some syntax that have not been successful.

```
 ALTER TABLE tableTest
-- ALTER COLUMN columnTest
ADD CONSTRAINT tableTest_columnTest_check
-- columnTest::jsonb = '["test1","test2","test3"]'::jsonb
-- CHECK (columnTest <@ ARRAY['test1', 'test2', 'test3'])
-- check tableTest.columnTest::jsonb ? 'attribute'
-- CHECK (columnTest IN {"type": "account creation"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `?|` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

```
ALTER TABLE tableTest
  ADD CONSTRAINT tableTest_columnTest_check
  columntest ?| array['test1','test2','test3']'
```

Note that this allows other values as well, so `["test1", "foobar"]` would be valid. It's unclear to me if that is OK or not.

If `columntest` really is defined with `jsonb` there is no need to cast it to that type.